# Does it make any sense to complain about App Store app review?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Apple has refused my app, but I can not accept reason. They said it is not able to fully loaded, but on all device, conditions etc. work well for me.

Do you think is it any chance they read my complain, and tries to recheck my app, or better to submit and wait an other 1 week for review?

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.2 and iPhone running iOS 8.2 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks. Specifically, we found that your app is unable to fully load and function.

Comment: I've edited out the part about other apps. Please edit in details about this particular app and whether the submitting Apple ID has any track record of passing or failing app reviews - beta or live on the store. What's still not clear is if you understand what part doesn't fully load or function on iOS 8.2 iPad - if you do, simply fix and resubmit.

Comment: Just because there are similar apps on the store doesn't mean they allow that feature in new submissions, or there could be some other reason. Ultimately they control the store.

Answer (score 1):

You can [request the review board](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) to review the complaint.

However, I would ask them what screen caused the bug - I've heard of times when a tester tried to use PassBook on an iPad when that functionality only loads on an iPhone. By asking politely, you'll better understand what code to cut from this submission rather than have to do that blindly and resubmit. You could also resubmit that exact build to TestFlight and ask to have it approved so you can have coverage for that build of that device from your testing pool.

Without seeing the text of the rejection it's hard to know what or why you got the no. Absolutely, make a new build and submit that for review. Even if it takes a week or two due to the crush of new apps for Apple Watch - you can always then make an appeal if the rejection doesn't make more sense in 48 hours time once you've looked it over and/or reached out to other developers to get their opinion of the situation.

Personally, I would thank them for the rejection. Offer a fixed build to address their specific complaints and only revert to an appeal after 6 weeks of unsuccessful attempts to get the initial version passed.

You don't say if this app has ever been approved - so allowing several months for that is realistic if the app isn't clearly something that has had significant engineering put into it.

Also - I find putting the app into TestFlight for beta allows you to discover sooner what points Apple sees as problematic with your app without it being a "go live" or "die in a fire" scenario.

TL;DR - find any way to give the reviewer what they ask in all or in part and try to avoid taking it to the review board until you're sure there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

If you've addressed their concerns in the *Resolution Center* and still think you want to continue, you're only option is to [submit an appeal](https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=appeal).

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/):

> The App Review Board provides the opportunity to appeal the rejection of an app if you believe that the functionality or technical implementation was misunderstood. You can submit additional details to the App Review Board to help them determine if your app should be reconsidered.

After that, you're done.  If they still reject it there isn't anything left to do.  I wouldn't go public with the app and the reason for the rejection, Apple doesn't look kindly on that.  In the end, it's their app store and they decide what goes in there.