# Apple rejected my app (twice), citing a very grey area violation but already have other similar apps on the Appstore. What can I do?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

After a painful conversation with the reviewer I was asked to remove our biggest USP and resubmit, however there is already a very popular app that blatantly offer the very same feature.

I didn't bring this up with the reviewer on the call as she was very VERY aggressive and this could potentially have made matter worse. Which option do I have now?

Comment: Also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179820/does-it-make-any-sense-to-complain-about-app-store-app-review